# lazarus version issue

Tags: software-installation, lazarus

I installed Lazarus 1.0.10 from Ubuntu, but installed FPC-SRC 2.6.2 from SourceForge.
I got down grade to 1.0.10 when I first run Lazarus after that I got leaks package does not exist every time I run Lazarus. I would like to know if it is possible to un install and re install to fix the issue?

Your help and information is great appreciated,

Regards,

Inung